# How to disable cookies for images, css and js files in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-5.4

I am developing website which have lot's of images like 30 on a single page I want to disable cookies for images so the loading time will be increase. I am using laravel 5.4. is there anything that i can do?

Comment: Do you mean cached data? Disabling cookies / images / css and JS files seems more like a browser thing which you will not be able to control

Comment: You can do using Javascript. But it will not support in all browser. So, best option is that you can manage it from HTACCESS.

Comment: How should I do it from HTACCESS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cache Busting** for **css** files and **javascript** files in [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting):

**Step 1 :**

Use `version` function in the end of your code in `gulf.js` file like this:

```
mix.sass('app.scss').version('css/app.css');
```

**Step 2:**:

When you need to use your file use it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: I don't have gulf.js. I have did it in webpack.mix.js. And it worked thanks. But if there is anything that i can do with images? that will be great.